# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to UPDATE multiple rows in single query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update, insert

I've come across people recommending using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to `UPDATE` multiple rows using a single query. Unfortunately no one seems to be using clean SQL (defining an obvious primary key of `id` and using at *least* two rows) and so I have not been able to confirm the effect to a satisfactory degree.

Presume all the data in the table exists and that some of the `quantity` rows will be different:

```
INSERT INTO variations (id, name, quantity) 
VALUES 
(1, 'John', 4), 
(2, 'Amy', 5), 
(3, 'Elizabeth', 6) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
id=VALUES(id), 
name=VALUES(name), 
quantity=VALUES(quantity);
```

If the quantities in the table are 1, 2 and 3 then what I've constituted is that the above query should `UPDATE` them to 4, 5 and 6. However manually running the command returns `Affected rows: 0` and the data in my application is beyond any doubt *not* changing.

Clarifications:

- The `name` rows may have their values change, I'm trying to keep the code simple.
- The `id` is the primary key and there are no other keys.
- No `UPDATE` *has* to happen if the all of the data for all of the row are the same between the query and table row.
- Sometimes only one column of data might change, sometimes all columns except `id` might change.
- There is no clarification in regards to `VALUES()` if it is using the `$row` (e.g. from PHP) data to `UPDATE` if it differs from what is already in the row.
- There is no clarification in regards to if all the columns must be specified (besides the the primary or a unique key).
- The documentation at both MariaDB and MySQL leaves a nebulous mystical cloud of unknowns.
- I'm running MariaDB 10.2.6 (MySQL 5.5.5).

I'm tempted just to dump the code in to a loop to run an `UPDATE` query *per row* as I don't have time to create a huge project out of this. None of the existing threads here or at SO properly address the **multiple UPDATE single query** issue (examples of using `case` look like monstrous nightmares to construct) and so I'm hoping for an answer that can clarify this beyond any doubt so I can learn from this frustrating challenge.

Comment: Is `Elizabeth` meant to have an id of 3? I can't see affected rows returning non-0 - at least in SQL. I'm not sure what you are asking. Here's [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a2ae1bbaa920745bb1a634f1ccb70f7e) of how I see your problem described and I don't see anything odd.  Maybe something at the PHP layer?

Comment: mariadb-10.2.6 is the [first stable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-102-series/) release of the 10.2 series and has since had 25 further compatible releases of bug fixes. I haven't checked all release notes to see if it fixes this however a version upgrade may be prudent. 10.2.X really not a 5.5.5 equalivant - that's just a number that used to trick replication with MySQL into working.

Comment: @danblack I'm having some oddities, some queries work and some don't. I just updated MariaDB to the latest stable and I'll get back here in the morning. I think the problem was in a serialized encode something or - it's late, mostly a note for myself. I'll edit the post with more full blown code if it's not related to an update to MariaDB. ︎

Comment: ODKU is performed by some unique constraint violation. Reassigning the values of the fields which causes ODKU execution makes no sense except DO NOTHING emulation (but INSERT IGNORE is more simple in such case).

Comment: You have two rows with `id=2`.  If that is a typo, please fix it.  If it is deliberate, please explain the intent.

Comment: @RickJames Typo, was trying to keep the example simple as the code in the system is a bit more complex. I managed to answer my own question though and make notes in my references.

Comment: 10.2 is approximately 5.7, two _major_ releases after 5.5.

Comment: @RickJames That is simply what MariaDB's version function returns.

Comment: @John - Ah, yes; that is confusing.  Here is what I got for a 10.2 instance for `@@version`:  `5.5.5-10.2.30-MariaDB-1:10.2.30+maria~bionic`.  The useful info is `10.2.30`.

Comment: I ran your test on multiple versions -- all gave rows affected as 6 (3 match + 3 change), and `SELECT *` gave the desired 4,5,6.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to #danblack and dbfiddle.uk in short I determined that I was missing one of the columns in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

**Every single column must be defined for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work!**

I effective had columns `id`, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in the table. I forgot to define one of the columns (that wasn't `id` as that is the first *half* of the requirement).

**Won't Work (missing column):**

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
id=VALUES(id), 
a=VALUES(a),
c=VALUES(c),
d=VALUES(d);
```

**Will Work (has all table columns):**

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
id=VALUES(id), 
a=VALUES(a),
b=VALUES(b),
c=VALUES(c),
d=VALUES(d);
```

Comment: What column is missing?  Why does it matter?  Please either make the question and answer fit together for the benefit of other readers.  (Else delete the Question.)

Comment: The first one will surely work as well. The only difference is that it will update a, c and d but not column b.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Perhaps the one column that I needed to `UPDATE` was the one I did not have? I don't recall though it doesn't change the fact that both you and I are simultaneously correct. :-)